# How do i add Likes Received to Structured Data in JSON-LD for Product Type

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I've been trying to figure out a way to add how many likes were received to a product using structured data. Is what I have below correct? Or would the second example be more correct?

Is my usage of ["Product","InteractionCounter"] for the type correct in the first example?

I'm trying to have the google show a likes counter much like the aggregateRating property of Product.

I'm also not sure what the url in offers is supposed to point to or if it's necessary. Any ideas?

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> 
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": ["Product","InteractionCounter"],
    "name": "CC-1",
    "description": "Wedding Cake",
    "interactionType":{
      "@type":"LikeAction",
      "name": "Likes",
      "description": "Likes Received"
    },
    "interactionService": {
      "@type":"WebSite",
      "url": "https://example.com/index.php?page=gallery"
    },
    "userInteractionCount": 55
  }
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> 
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "CC-1",
    "description": "Wedding Cake",
    "additionalProperty": {
      "@type": "PropertyValue",
      "name": "Likes",
      "description": "Likes Received",
      "value": 55
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is what I have right now:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": ["Product","InteractionCounter"],
    "name": "CC-1",
    "description": "Wedding Cake with bla bla bla",
    "category": "Wedding Cakes",
    "brand": {
      "@type": "Brand",
      "logo": "https://example.com/images/logo.png",
      "slogan": "Cakes Are Nice"
    },
    "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "https://example.com/anvil",
        "priceCurrency": "CAD",
        "price": "119.99"
      },
    "image": "https://example.com/collection/wedding_cakes/mid_def/CC-1",
    "interactionType":{
      "@type":"LikeAction",
      "name": "Likes",
      "description": "Likes Received"
    },
    "interactionService": {
      "@type":"WebSite",
      "url": "https://mimozas.com/index.php?page=gallery"
    },
    "userInteractionCount": "55 PLACEHOLDER"
  }
```

Comment: looks like it can't be done. According to Schema.org, it seems that only organizations, creative works and persons can be liked, while products can be reviewed and rated.. so, no, that's not a correct markup, although syntactically correct. And product isn't interaction counter, so adding that type also doesn't fit..

Comment: you can affect Google's SERP only to the extent they describe it in their official documentation, everything else is created/decided by their algorithms. There seems to be no mention of "likes counter" in the Product's docs, so no point adding it for SERP purposes, as mentioned below, even if that would be possible with product markup

Comment: Thnx guys. I'm hoping google adds that in the future. my thinking is if their system picks up on people doing that they'll add it. So ultimately would the best method be using subjectOf as outlined in the answer below?

Comment: same problem, [subjectOf](https://schema.org/subjectOf) is meant for creative work or event, not product. For your case to work, [interactionStatistic](https://schema.org/interactionStatistic) should be available to product, like so: https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/2421. in the meantime, perhaps you could utilize [EndorsementRating](https://schema.org/EndorsementRating) - _An EndorsementRating is a rating that expresses some level of endorsement, for example inclusion in a "critic's pick" blog, a "Like" or "+1" on a social network_

Comment: another option would be to add [CreativeWork](https://schema.org/CreativeWork) type to the product type, similar to what you tried in your first example, which would then enable using interaction stats, but in your case I don't think that fits.. (since cakes aren't listed as a creative work..)

Answer (score 1):

If the product is the subject of content, then it makes sense to indicate likes as part of the type Product. My suggestion for you:

```js
{"@context":"https://schema.org",
"@type":"Product",
"name":"CC-1",
"description":"Wedding Cake",
"subjectOf":{
"@type": "InteractionCounter",
"interactionType":{
"@type":"LikeAction",
"name":"Likes",
"description":"Likes Received"
},
"interactionService":{
"@type":"WebSite",
"url":"https://example.com/index.php?page=gallery"
},
"userInteractionCount":"55"
}
}
```

And be careful about inverted commas.

My addition after expanding the question.

> I'm trying to have the google show a likes counter much like the
> aggregateRating property of Product.

Google has no direct support for the type InteractionCounter - read more **[Explore the search gallery](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/search-gallery)**. However, in the rich test results of my suggestion, there are no errors or warning messages from Google:

[image]

Probably needs experimentation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by subject of content. I just have a product page that has products.

Comment: I have a product page that has products with prices pictures etc. each div takes up a portion of the page and contains one product. Think of it as a catalogue. Just a warning for anyone attempting this google states that they do not support multiple products' structured data in 1 page. I'm trying to have the rich snippets show a likes counter much like the aggregate rating feature. I will update my question to be more clear. sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: I don't believe Google has a like rich snippet. If they did they would document how to mark it up.

Comment: "I'm not sure what you mean by subject of content. I just have a product page that has products". One product is the content subject.